# can't get odbc working in apache

Tags: php, linux, apache2, odbc, unixodbc

I installed unixODBC by using apt-get install, and now when I try to use odbc_connect() is still get this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function odbc_connect()
```

what do i need to do to configure it to work with php?  I have been looking online but I can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to install php5-odbc also. unixODBC provides the driver manager, but you need the PHP code that calls it.

Comment: If I install php5-odbc, do I need to do any further configuration before I can use odbc_connect()? I installed that package, but can't get it to work. Perhaps a reboot of the machine would do it (although I don't know when I will be able to)?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on CentOS 6.3 with PHP 5.3.16. But the fix was to use yum to install php-odbc.

```
yum install php-odbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  Check the documentation for your server, it may require third-party libraries to be in a specific sub-directory, or have some other mechanism for finding them.  If so, you should be able to create a symbolic link to the library.  That way, if it gets updated, your server will automatically use it.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem also.  We installed php5-odbc, and still had the problem.  Turns out we needed to reboot Linux for php to see the function.  Recycling Apache was not enough!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable `odbc` extension for your Apache by `a2enmod odbc`.

Then check if exists by: `apache2ctl -M`.

If you don't have this extension, install via `apt-get install php-odbc` (use `yum` in case of CentOS).

See also: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).